# Is there a way to make a D3 force layout continually move?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Is there a way to may a d3 force layout continually move even after it has "cooled"? I have been using this but the movement is very minor:

```
svg.on('mousemove', function() {
   force.start();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured it out on my own with this:

```
setInterval(function(){force.alpha(0.1);},250);
```

That's probably not the most performant on a large layout but it provides a nice continual drift on my force layout of 20 nodes.

Answer (score 2):

As other answerers have noted the simulation's [`alpha`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_alpha) parameter controls the amount of heat in the system. The rate of decay of that heat determines how fast the force layout cools down to a halt, which happens as soon as `alpha` reaches [`alphaMin`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_alphaMin).

For D3 v3 or lower the other answers are the way to go pumping energy into the simulation by manipulating `alpha`. As of D3 v4, however, you can use [`simulation.alphaDecay()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/simulation.js#L106) to directly control the rate of decay of `alpha`. Setting the decay rate to 0 will keep the simulation running infinitely. That way, you can set a level of `alpha` at your discretion and keep it at the exact same level the entire time.

For a runnable demo have a look at the following snippet adapted from Mike Bostocks [*Force-Directed Tree*](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-tree) notebook:

```js
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json")
  .then(data => {
  const width = 400;
  const height = 400;
  const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  const links = root.links();
  const nodes = root.descendants();

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
      .force("x", d3.forceX())
      .force("y", d3.forceY())
      .alphaDecay(0);

  const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height]);

  const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#999")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line");

  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : "#000")
      .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
      .attr("r", 3.5);

  node.append("title")
      .text(d => d.data.name);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cooling and amount of movement is controlled by the [`alpha` parameter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#alpha). If you want to keep the layout running continuously, reset alpha to be non-zero:

```
force.alpha(0.1);
```

Note that even though alpha may be greater than zero, there's not necessarily going to be any (significant) movement. At some point, the layout will settle into its equilibrium state and to get a significant change you'll have to e.g. move one of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a function instead of a value.

```
.alpha(() => 0.1)
```